# RealmSwift/Object.swift + Expressions are not allowed at the top level

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, realm

I am new to Realm & try to pod 'RealmSwift' to my swift test project. But it seems there few compilation issue coming up when I install pod for realmswift.

[image]

Please let me know what am I missing here. 
Xcode version: 7.2

Pod file detail: 
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'RealmSwift'

Deployment target: 9.2 iPhone 6 plus simulator
Using Realm (0.97.0)
Using RealmSwift (0.97.0)

Thanks in Advance
Manoj

Comment: Have you opened the correct project? The pod version has some extra headers... Also, make sure to do a clean after porting a project to pod

Comment: Yes, Correct project with correct target. My project is contain only one viewcontroller (very simple project). I did clean 2-3 times and removed all derived data too.

Comment: Which version of CocoaPods do you use?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me on the empty lines - **deleting these empty lines** solves the issue (seems that some weird characters are present in a sample code).